# Meteor + Phonegap

Tags: facebook, cordova, oauth, meteor, geolocation

I'm beginning to develop a Meteor App using Phonegap, however I've come to a stumbling block on GeoLocation and Facebook Oauth. How do I extract native GeoLocation information from PhoneGap and transfer that to Meteor, and how do I create a native Facebook Login from the app as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have made it working, 
you just need the www folder of cordova bundle app,
and then create a hello world cordova app and replace your www folder in it.

Add plugins you need manually,

Here is my app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.youiest.tapmatrix
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tapmate/id774935608?mt=8

but yes, I did not succeeded in create facebook native login with the meteor official way.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to make facebook native login work.

You just need to add official cordova plugin for facebook and configure it in mobile-config.js

In case of trouble, please follow tutorial [here](http://www.rishabhsinghal.in/meteor-cordova-facebook-single-sign-on/)